# How to trigger other button state with single button without execute their own algorithm?

Tags: android, button, togglebutton

I have 4 toggle button with specific drawable and algoritm that sending sms to specific phone number, if toggle button is checked, it sends ON, else, it sends OFF.

```
    btnsms.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()

    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay1on");
                textsms.setText("1 MURUB");
            } else {

                sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay1off");
                textsms.setText("1 MATI");
            }
        }
    });


    btnsms2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()

    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay2on");
                textsms2.setText("2 MURUB");
            } else {

                sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay2off");
                textsms2.setText("2 MATI");
            }
        }
    });

    btnsms3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()

    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay3on");
                textsms3.setText("3 MURUB");
            } else {

                sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay3off");
                textsms3.setText("3 MATI");
            }
        }
    });

    btnsms4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()

    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay4on");
                textsms4.setText("4 MURUB");
            } else {

                sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay4off");
                textsms4.setText("4 MATI");
            }
        }
    });
```

But, if i have so many button, it would be difficult to click 1 by 1. So, I decide to make 1 button that could trigger all of them. So, with this single button, all other buttons's state will be ON/OFF directly.

```
   btnsms5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()

    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                sendSMS("+6285800486251", "semuaon");
                textsms5.setText("ALL MURUB");
                btnsms.setChecked(true);
                btnsms2.setChecked(true);
                btnsms3.setChecked(true);
                btnsms4.setChecked(true);
            } else {

                sendSMS("+6285800486251", "semuaoff");
                textsms5.setText("ALL MATI");
                btnsms.setChecked(false);
                btnsms2.setChecked(false);
                btnsms3.setChecked(false);
                btnsms4.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

My problem is,  when I click the Trigger button, it triggered all of others as I program it to be, but it also send SMS.

I need to trigger others with this single button without trigger their SMS algorithm.
I will thank you if you can help me.

UPDATE :
I have this background XML(selector) to change automatically the background image depend on the state of the button.

```
     item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_lamp_icon_on" android:state_checked="true"
     item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_lamp_icon_off" android:state_checked="false"
```

Comment: I am not understanding your question, you said that, you need to trigger all buttons with one single button, this is ok. But your asking again don't want to execute sms algorithm. How you are writing the code in the "setOnCheckedChangeListener" then it should execute.

Comment: Yes Sir, thats my problem, The simple analogy is, I have 4 switches to turn ON/OFF lamp each switch. But, I need single switch to trigger 4 others. And I also can make it OFF 1 by 1 or using trigger switch to OFF. But, I need them to SMS me once using SMS instruction in trigger switch. Override the 4 others SMS instruction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the checked state of the buttons and these buttons have `setOnCheckedChangeListener` which listen to the checked state changes. If you don't want that remove `sendSMS()` methods in the `setOnCheckedChangeListener`.

When you want to send SMS then add `sendSMS()` method along with changing the checked state.

Comment: Yes Sir, this is my purpose, but Im newbie here and still confused to do that

Comment: Where are you placing `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` methods of btnsms4, btnsms3, btnsms2, btnsms? Are you placing them inside `btnsms5.setOnCheckedChangeListener()`?

Comment: No Sir, I place them above the btnsms5

Comment: I have try to change only the background, it worked and didnt send SMS, but the state of the button didnt change, and also if I turn it OFF using each button, the background didnt change cause of the trigger button

Comment: Yes, Sir. Your answer helped me to think to that way, and finally I solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

as per i know last time i did the same kind of functionality using array or array list it will do the magic just look at the below code and made your logic have a good day :)

```
ToggleButton toggleButton[] = new ToggleButton[3];
//access it using findViewbyid one by one 
toggleButton[0] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton00);
toggleButton[1] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);
toggleButton[2] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton02);
toggleButton[3] = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton03);


    //below code for clickable event
    int arrayindex = 0;
    int viewcount = 0;
    while (arrayindex < 3) {

        View v = asyncLayout.getChildAt(viewcount);
        if (yourclickableToggleposition) {

            //no check
        }else{

           //all of your button will be checked instead of clickable   
           //button
           toggleButton[arrayindex].setChecked(true);
            arrayindex ++;
        }
        viewcount ++ ;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `button.setEnable(true)`.
It will change button's view state.

++

```
class CustomButton extends Button {
    public void setState(boolean isOn) {
        offView.setVisibility(isOn ? INVISIBLE : VISIBLE);
        onView.setVisibility(isOn ? INVISIBLE : VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: This method made me disable the button, I dont need to do that. I just need to change the state with changed background as Indicator, not to disable that. I need to make all ON/OFF but still can trigger it 1 by 1. Not disabling them

Comment: hmm then create custom Button View which can change it's ON/OFF layout.

Comment: Ok Sir, i will try it

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

Maybe you can follow this solution

```
final boolean[] isOnlyUpdate = {false};

    //For button 1,2,3,4 add if (!isOnlyUpdate[0]) {} to make selection

    btnsms.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (!isOnlyUpdate[0]) { 
                if (isChecked) {
                    sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay1on");
                    textsms.setText("1 MURUB");
                } else {

                    sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay1off");
                    textsms.setText("1 MATI");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //for button 2,3,4 can follow button 1

    btnsms5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            isOnlyUpdate[0] = true;
            if (isChecked) {
                sendSMS("+6285800486251", "semuaon");
                textsms5.setText("ALL MURUB");
            } else {
                sendSMS("+6285800486251", "semuaoff");
                textsms5.setText("ALL MATI");
            }
            btnsms.setChecked(isChecked);
            btnsms2.setChecked(isChecked);
            btnsms3.setChecked(isChecked);
            btnsms4.setChecked(isChecked);
            isOnlyUpdate[0] =false;
        }
    });
}
```

just add one variable to handle it & check it befor send SMS

Comment: Thankyou sir, but your answer dont do any changes.

Comment: Sir, I have try it. But, same with my code, it still execute the SMS. I just need to override each button SMS with this trigger button SMS.

Comment: @BurhanuddinRabbani you mean you only want change state but not execute the SMS ? ah sorry

Comment: Yes Sir, if I click the toggle button 1,2,3,4 directly, it will turn ON/OFF and send SMS ON/OFF each button I pressed. Then, if I press the trigger button (btnsms5), It will override the 1234 button operation state but, dont send their sms instruction and change it with btnsms5 own sms instruction

Comment: @BurhanuddinRabbani Try my edited again :D, hopefully can solve your problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126069/discussion-between-sodiq-and-burhanuddin-rabbani).

Comment: I didt use your advice yet, Sir

Comment: Ahahaha no problem :D

Answer (score 0):

finally I got what I need.
My code is a part of application that sending SMS as a command to the Arduino, then arduino will proccess the command and execute the relay to turn ON/OFF the relay.

The Arduino code and Android App code are similar. So, I do take a look my Arduino code and adaptate it to my Android code. This fixed my problem. I just need to add commparation 5th toggle button state to each other button.

```
    btnsms.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()

    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                if(btnsms5.isChecked()) {


                    textsms.setText("1 MURUB");
                }else {
                    sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay1on");
                    textsms.setText("1 MURUB");

                }


            } else {

                if (btnsms5.isChecked()) {

                    sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay1off");
                    textsms.setText("1 MATI");
                }
                else{
                    textsms.setText("1 MATI");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    btnsms2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()

    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                if(btnsms5.isChecked()) {


                    textsms2.setText("2 MURUB");
                }else {
                    sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay2on");
                    textsms2.setText("2 MURUB");

                }


            } else {

                if (btnsms5.isChecked()) {

                    sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay2off");
                    textsms2.setText("2 MATI");
                }
                else{
                    textsms2.setText("2 MATI");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    btnsms3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()

    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                if(btnsms5.isChecked()) {


                    textsms3.setText("3 MURUB");
                }else {
                    sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay3on");
                    textsms3.setText("3 MURUB");

                }


            } else {

                if (btnsms5.isChecked()) {

                    sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay3off");
                    textsms3.setText("3 MATI");
                }
                else{
                    textsms3.setText("3 MATI");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    btnsms4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()

    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                if(btnsms5.isChecked()) {


                    textsms4.setText("4 MURUB");
                }else {
                    sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay4on");
                    textsms4.setText("4 MURUB");

                }


            } else {

                if (btnsms5.isChecked()) {

                    sendSMS("+6285800486251", "relay4off");
                    textsms4.setText("4 MATI");
                }
                else{
                    textsms4.setText("4 MATI");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    btnsms5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                sendSMS("+6285800486251", "semuaon");

                btnsms.setChecked(true);
                btnsms2.setChecked(true);
                btnsms3.setChecked(true);
                btnsms4.setChecked(true);
                textsms5.setText("ALL MURUB");

            } else {
                sendSMS("+6285800486251", "semuaoff");

                btnsms.setChecked(false);
                btnsms2.setChecked(false);
                btnsms3.setChecked(false);
                btnsms4.setChecked(false);
                textsms5.setText("ALL MATI");

            }
        }
    });
```

Thankyou for your help :)